# How can I listen for drupalOverlayBeforeClose in custom jQuery?

Tags: 7, javascript, modal-dialogs

I am monitoring a particular form for changes and want to warn the user before they attempt to navigate away from the form without submitting it. I've successfully gotten this working in all instances except for the overlay close button – because that element is bound to the `Drupal.overlay.close()` function, a user is able to click it and immediately close the overlay, even though I'm listening for all `$('a')` clicks.

I looked inside of `modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js` and see that it provides the `drupalOverlayBeforeClose` event so that other scripts can respond and stop the overlay from closing if needed, but I can't figure out how to implement this. Do I just listen for this event globally, through the `$(document)` or something? Or do I need to extend the Drupal object and attach my function to this event somehow?

Comment: Let me add that listening via `$(document). drupalOverlayBeforeClose(function() { alert('foo'); })` never fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the following code,

```
jQuery(document).bind('drupalOverlayBeforeClose', function(event) {
   // your code
   return false // This will prevent the overlay from closing.
});
```

click, dbclick and other methods are shortcut methods for `bind('click', function(){})`, `bind('dbclick', function(){})` respectively. However there is no shortcut method called **drupalOverlayBeforeClose**, that's why the following code didn't worked,

```
$(document).drupalOverlayBeforeClose(function(event) {

});
```

So you need to bind **drupalOverlayBeforeClose** explicitly using bind. If you return false in your callback, then the overlay won't be closed.

Hope this clarifies the answer.

Comment: This helps a lot. I should have tried binding that sooner and not treated it like a shortcut. 

I'm still experiencing an issue where the event that is passed into the function doesn't seem to be the event that I want. For example, if I do `$(document).bind('drupalOverlayBeforeClose', function(event) { event.preventDefault();` and then run `if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) { alert('foo'); }` in overlay-parent.js I see no 'foo'. Is the event being passed into function() the proper "event"?

Comment: Added the information about preventing the overlay from closing in the answer :)

Comment: `return false;` isn't doing it for me. overlay-parent.js is checking `if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) { return false; }` which is why I tried `preventDefault()`.

Comment: No need to try preventDefault(), just return false that's enough. Look at the comment before that line - **If a handler returned false, the close will be prevented.**. You're making the things more complicated :(

Comment: `return false;` does nothing – the overlay still immediately closes. I read all of the comments, but I can clearly see that the code is looking for `isDefaultPrevented()`.

Comment: Does `return false` in an event handler cause the preventDefault() state to change?

Comment: Its working perfectly fine for me. Show your code so that I can say where its going wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6302/discussion-between-mathankumar-and-charlie-s)

Comment: Chat was helpful. While this code does show a popup: `var confirm = window.confirm(Drupal.t("You will lose all unsaved work."));return confirm;` the overlay still immediately closes regardless of what choice the user selects. It looks like the event object is completely empty in the listener. I've even moved this into a standalone JS file (outside of my behavior attach) and it's still empty.

Comment: Is your .js file being called by your front-end theme, or the admin theme?

Comment: It's attached via ['#attached']['js'] to the node edit form in a module.

Answer (score 3):

Try following code

```
jQuery("#overlay-container").find("iframe").contents().find("#overlay-close").click(function (event) {
    console.log('Clicked on close overlay link');

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var r = confirm("Do you want to close overlay?");
    if (r == true) {
        Drupal.overlay.close();
    } else {
        //do something else
    }


});
```

When user will click on close overlay link, a confirming dialog should display.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya. I'm trying to listen when the event is triggered (`drupalOverlayBeforeClose`) and have gotten it working thanks to you and mashemetician's code – the issue was with the scope of the event between the parent and the iframe. The issue I still have, however, is that if I press "cancel" the first time, the X never listens for subsequent clicks. Do you have that behavior when you use your code?

Comment: No that behavior does not happen with my code. I can still listen for subsequent clicks.